# Positive to Negative and Negative to Positive number in a Calculator

Tags: objective-c

I just started my journey in Objective-C and my first application that I'm trying to do is fully operational basic calculator.

Haven said that. I have already made it to work the plus, minus, multiply and division when two inputs are entered and then the equals button is pressed. But now for the +/- operation and percentage %. I want them to be self operation.

Hows that? Well, I want them to work as they work in the iPhone running iOS7 calculator when you input one number and then press either +/- or percentage the output is immediately display as the result without the need of inputing another number and pressing the equal sign.

I have tried following the method that I have been using for far but I have to press twice the button to show the display which is not what I'm looking for..

This is my code..

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number2:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 2;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number3:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 3;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number4:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 4;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number5:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 5;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number6:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 6;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number7:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 7;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number8:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 8;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number9:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 9;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}
-(IBAction)Number0:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 0;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}

-(IBAction)Times:(id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 1;
    SelectNumber = 0;

}
-(IBAction)Divide:(id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 2;
    SelectNumber = 0;

}
-(IBAction)Substract:(id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 3;
    SelectNumber = 0;

}
-(IBAction)Plus:(id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 4;
    SelectNumber = 0;

}

- (IBAction)Percent:(id)sender {

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 5;
    SelectNumber = 0;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", RunningTotal];

}

- (IBAction)PositiveOrNegative:(id)sender {

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(RunningTotal > 0){
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
                } else{
                    RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 6;
    SelectNumber = 0;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", RunningTotal];


}


- (IBAction)Dot:(id)sender {



}

-(IBAction)Equals:(id)sender{

    if (RunningTotal == 0) {
        RunningTotal = SelectNumber;
    } else{
        switch (Method) {
            case 1:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal - SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SelectNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal / 100;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    Method = 0;
    SelectNumber = 0;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", RunningTotal];

}


-(IBAction)AllClear:(id)sender{

    Method = 0;
    RunningTotal = 0;
    SelectNumber = 0;

    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Well, any help or suggestions are extremely appreciated it. Please, if you need more info regarding my post or any questions that may help to understand better my question, please let me know and I will provide them.. :)

Comment: your Screen instance is what type of view? UITextField?

Comment: This is my Screen instance @interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Screen;
}

Comment: Could you clarify whether your question is a UI issue or logic issue and narrow it down? I'm not sure whether you're having trouble calculating something, or whether you don't know how to update the display properly. As an aside, I would separate the UI code (i.e. entering and displaying numbers) from the logic code (i.e. interpreting the entered numbers and operations into results).

Comment: Oh.  Try `[Screen setNeedsDisplay]` ?

Comment: is not logic issue. The calculation is good the problem is an UI issue @whooops

Comment: @stevesliva where should I try that? not sure how that works

Comment: Right after you set Screen.text, I'd guess.  I'm not confident about it, or it'd be an answer.  But if you change UIView content and the view's not redrawing, it would seem to be useful.

Comment: @stevesliva ok, I have tried but still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like a bug:

```
        case 6:
            if(RunningTotal > 0){
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * -1;
            } else{
                RunningTotal = RunningTotal * +1;
            }
```

I don't think you ever want to multiply by +1 ... to flip the sign of a negative number, you would also multiply by -1

I'd also recommend encapsulating the duplicated switch on Method in a function.

Additionally, you've got a few other things that are frowned upon with Objective-C going on... you should modify instance variables with setters and getters.  And you should use @property to have the iVars and accessors created for you.  And your iVars and functions should start with a lowercase letter, while classes start with uppercase.  Your ViewController class should have a function-specific name.  Your ViewController class should have a prefix all your own because Objective C doesn't support namespaces.

Comment: Actually, the simplest is to `RunningTotal = - RunningTotal`.

Comment: @Sulthan, yep.  And traditionally the most efficient, though I bet compilers are wise to it now.

Comment: @stevesliva thanks, just changed. what do u mean encapsulating the switch in a function? just creating a function with the switch inside and then call it?

Comment: Yes.  It's good practice to encapsulate code that you duplicate that many times.

Comment: @stevesliva thanks... I will.. any idea regarding how to display the result of my positive to negative calculation immediately after I pressed the button in the Screen?

Comment: Update Screen.text like in your number methods.

Comment: @stevesliva hows is that?